# Сервер на Java для Android приложения

Tags: javascript, java, android, сервер, http

Мне нужно сделать сервер на java, который будет работать с БД и выполнять другие функции. Выбор пал на сервер на основе REST API. Главное, он должен отвечать на HTTP запросы приходящие с клиентского Android приложения. Само клиентское приложение содержит WebView, в котором отображается сайт расположенный локально. Запрос я отправляю с помощью JS, но как бы я не старался, результат один...

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Подскажите как это исправить. Возможно полностью изменить архитектуру или инструментарий. Главное, чтобы сервер был написан на Java.

Comment: Надо на сервере разрешить CORS. Гуглите, как это сделать для вашего сервера.

Comment: Спасибо! Раньше даже и не слышал о CORS, теперь буду знать.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Добавления CORS в Spring:

1. Можно добавить аннотацию @CrossOrigin перед контроллером.
2. Можно объявить глобально, для этого добавляем Bean в главном классе 
   приложения. Пример:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
}
```